# Attendance IN and OUT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following table structure and sample data -

```
EmpID InputDateTime      StatusINOUT
-------------------------------------
1     2018-05-26 08:44     1
1     2018-05-26 08:44     2
2     2018-05-28 08:44     1
2     2018-05-28 12:44     2                   
1     2018-05-21 08:44     1
1     2018-05-21 10:44     2
2     2018-05-23 08:44     1
2     2018-05-23 08:44     2
```

Now I want to separate column `InputDateTime` into two columns i.e., `INTIME(1)` and `OUTTIME(2)`. The logic behind this is the date for which `StatusInOut` is 1 will be `InTime` and for `StatusInOut` is 2 that date value will be `OUTTIME(2)`.

The expected output format is as shown below:

```
Empid   INTIME(1)          OUTIME(2)
--------------------------------------------
1      2018-05-26 08:44    2018-05-26 08:44
2      2018-05-28 08:44    2018-05-28 12:44
1      2018-05-21 08:44    2018-05-21 10:44
2      2018-05-23 08:44    2018-05-23 08:44
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/separat-data-in-column-sttusinout-wise-into-two-columns   please follow link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query using join and update.

```
create table #tempStatus (EmpId int, intTime datetime, sStatus int)        
insert into #tempStatus        
values(1, '2018-05-26 08:44', 1),        
    (1, '2018-05-26 08:44', 2),        
    (2, '2018-05-28 08:44', 1),        
    (2, '2018-05-28 12:44', 2),            
    (1, '2018-05-21 08:44', 1),        
    (1, '2018-05-21 10:44', 2),            
    (2, '2018-05-23 08:44', 1),        
    (2, '2018-05-23 08:44', 2)  
    ,(3, '2018-05-23 08:44', 1)  

select EmpId, MIN(intTime) as intTime, MAX(intTime) as OutTime into #tempA from (      
select EmpId, intTime, intTime as OutTime      
from #tempStatus where sStatus = 1      
)a       
group by EmpId, intTime      

update s      
set s.OutTime = t.outTime      
from #tempA s      
left join     
(    
select EmpId, MAX(outTime) as outTime from(       
select EmpId, intTime as outTime      
from #tempStatus where sStatus = 2      
)b       
group by empId,outTime) t     
on s.EmpId = t.EmpId and Convert(Varchar,s.OutTime,112) =  Convert(Varchar,t.outTime,112)      

select * from #tempA order by EmpId      

drop table #tempA      
DROP TABLE #tempStatus
```

OR you can also try the below one query

```
select empid, 
       max(case when sStatus = 1 then intTime end) as INTIME,
       max(case when sStatus = 2 then intTime end) as OUTIME
from (select t.*, 
             row_number () over ( order by inttime) as seq1,
             row_number () over (partition by empid order by inttime) as seq2
      from #tempStatus t
     ) t
group by empid, (seq1-seq2);
```

Check for the similar answers - [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53832254/how-to-separate-data-into-two-columns/53832932#53832932)

Answer (score 2):

use case when

```
select empid,max(case when statusINOut=1 then Datetime end)  as INtime,
max(case when statusINOut=2 then Datetime end)  as Outtime
from table_name t
group by empid,convert(date,Datetime)
```

Comment: if one empid have multiple records then it records are not coming except one record

Comment: convert datetime in date and put in group by btw what is your dbms mysql,oracle or sqlserver else

Comment: SQLserver dbms ,and i have converted datetime in date

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select EmpID
  , min(DateTime) INTIME(1)
  , max(DateTime) OUTIME(2)
from TABLE
group by EmpID;
```

Comment: it is not returning exact result which i want, which i shared

Comment: try this,                                                                                                      
 select EmpID, min(DateTime) INTIME, max(DateTime) OUTIME
 from (select EmpID, DateTime, trunc(DateTime), statusINOut
             from TABLE_T)
 group by EmpID, trunc(DateTime);