# How To Separate Data Into Two Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Consider the following table structure and sample data -

```
EmpID InputDateTime      StatusINOUT
-------------------------------------
1     2018-05-26 08:44     1
1     2018-05-26 08:44     2
2     2018-05-28 08:44     1
2     2018-05-28 12:44     2                   
1     2018-05-21 08:44     1
1     2018-05-21 10:44     2
2     2018-05-23 08:44     1
2     2018-05-23 08:44     2
```

Now I want to separate column `InputDateTime` into two columns i.e., `INTIME(1)` and `OUTTIME(2)`. The logic behind this is the date for which `StatusInOut` is 1 will be `InTime` and for `StatusInOut` is 2 that date value will be `OUTTIME(2)`.

The expected output format is as shown below:

```
Empid   INTIME(1)          OUTIME(2)
--------------------------------------------
1      2018-05-26 08:44    2018-05-26 08:44
2      2018-05-28 08:44    2018-05-28 12:44
1      2018-05-21 08:44    2018-05-21 10:44
2      2018-05-23 08:44    2018-05-23 08:44
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
create table #tempStatus (EmpId int, intTime datetime, sStatus int)    
insert into #tempStatus    
values(1, '2018-05-26 08:44', 1),    
    (1, '2018-05-26 08:44', 2),    
    (2, '2018-05-28 08:44', 1),    
    (2, '2018-05-28 12:44', 2),        
    (1, '2018-05-21 08:44', 1),    
    (1, '2018-05-21 10:44', 2),        
    (2, '2018-05-23 08:44', 1),    
    (2, '2018-05-23 08:44', 2)    

select EmpId, MIN(intTime) as intTime, MIN(intTime) as OutTime into #tempA from (  
select EmpId, intTime, intTime as OutTime  
from #tempStatus where sStatus = 1  
)a   
group by EmpId, intTime  

select EmpId, MAX(outTime) as outTime into #tempB from(   
select EmpId, intTime as outTime  
from #tempStatus where sStatus = 2  
)b   
group by empId,outTime     

select * from #tempA order by EmpId  

drop table #tempA  
drop table #tempB  
DROP TABLE #tempStatus
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `row_number()`s & use differences of them to do conditional aggregation, This also called as `Gaps and Islands` problem :

```
select empid, 
       max(case when sStatus = 1 then intTime end) as INTIME,
       max(case when sStatus = 2 then intTime end) as OUTIME
from (select t.*, 
             row_number () over ( order by inttime) as seq1,
             row_number () over (partition by empid order by inttime) as seq2
      from #tempStatus t
     ) t
group by empid, (seq1-seq2);
```

**EDIT :** If you want to display `OutTime` whenever `InTime` it not there, then you can use subquery :

```
select t.empid, 
       coalesce(INTIME, OUTIME) as INTIME,
       coalesce(OUTIME, INTIME) as OUTIME
from ( <query here> 
     ) t;
```

Comment: Any idea how can handle if outtime is not there for date like, (3, '2018-05-23 08:44', 1)

Comment: @SurajKumar. . . In that case it will display `null` value.

Comment: Your query gets wrong result when InTime is not there e.g., for -   (5, '2018-05-23 08:44', 2). However it doesn't happen in real life scenario.

Comment: @SurajKumar. . . This has desired behavior & of course if the `InTime` is not there, then it will display `null` value. I think you actually need to `OutTime` there if the `InTime` is not there.

Comment: The result is wrong. It is combining rows unnecessarily. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bb492e6aa0b3adb669cda80d73aaad2d

Comment: The approach is wrong as well. This is **not** a gaps and islands problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of matching end time with a start time:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT EmpId, intTime, sStatus
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY intTime) AS rn
    FROM #tempStatus
)
SELECT o.EmpId, i.intTime AS INTIME, o.intTime AS OUTIME
FROM cte o
LEFT JOIN cte AS i ON i.EmpId = o.EmpId AND i.rn = o.rn - 1 AND i.sStatus = 1
WHERE o.sStatus = 2
```

[**Demo on DB<>Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6132142f9e5fec339b7298349b1cbf9d) and [**some tests**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b4d7e96846a5c71efd053b268c54144)

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 r2 there LAG is not available.

Comment: @SurajKumar see revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this PIVOT
Sample data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#tempStatus')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tempStatus

CREATE TABLE #TEMPSTATUS (EMPID INT, INTTIME DATETIME, SSTATUS INT)    
INSERT INTO #TEMPSTATUS    
VALUES(1, '2018-05-26 08:44', 1),    
    (1, '2018-05-26 08:44', 2),    
    (2, '2018-05-28 08:44', 1),    
    (2, '2018-05-28 12:44', 2),        
    (1, '2018-05-21 08:44', 1),    
    (1, '2018-05-21 10:44', 2),        
    (2, '2018-05-23 08:44', 1),    
    (2, '2018-05-23 08:44', 2)
```

Sql script

```
SELECT Empid,[INTIME(1)],[OUTIME(2)]
FROM
(
    SELECT EmpId,intTime, CASE WHEN sStatus=1 THEN 'INTIME(1)' 
                       WHEN sStatus=2 THEN 'OUTIME(2)'  END INOutTimes
    FROM #tempStatus
    ) AS SRC
    PIVOT 
    (MAX(intTime) FOR INOutTimes IN ([INTIME(1)],[OUTIME(2)])
    ) AS PVT
UNION ALL
SELECT Empid,[INTIME(1)],[OUTIME(2)]
FROM
(
    SELECT EmpId,intTime, CASE WHEN sStatus=1 THEN 'INTIME(1)' 
                       WHEN sStatus=2 THEN 'OUTIME(2)'  END INOutTimes
    FROM #tempStatus
    ) AS SRC
    PIVOT 
    (MIN(intTime) FOR INOutTimes IN ([INTIME(1)],[OUTIME(2)])
    ) AS PVT
```

Result

```
Empid    INTIME(1)                   OUTIME(2)
---------------------------------------------------------------
1       2018-05-26 08:44:00.000     2018-05-26 08:44:00.000
2       2018-05-28 08:44:00.000     2018-05-28 12:44:00.000
1       2018-05-21 08:44:00.000     2018-05-21 10:44:00.000
2       2018-05-23 08:44:00.000     2018-05-23 08:44:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and find out the solution after updating with inner join as shown below. Here I have skipped the date and row where InTime is not there.

```
create table #tempStatus (EmpId int, intTime datetime, sStatus int)        
insert into #tempStatus        
values(1, '2018-05-26 08:44', 1),        
    (1, '2018-05-26 08:44', 2),        
    (2, '2018-05-28 08:44', 1),        
    (2, '2018-05-28 12:44', 2),            
    (1, '2018-05-21 08:44', 1),        
    (1, '2018-05-21 10:44', 2),            
    (2, '2018-05-23 08:44', 1),        
    (2, '2018-05-23 08:44', 2)  
    ,(3, '2018-05-23 08:44', 1)  

select EmpId, MIN(intTime) as intTime, MAX(intTime) as OutTime into #tempA from (      
select EmpId, intTime, intTime as OutTime      
from #tempStatus where sStatus = 1      
)a       
group by EmpId, intTime      

update s      
set s.OutTime = t.outTime      
from #tempA s      
left join     
(    
select EmpId, MAX(outTime) as outTime from(       
select EmpId, intTime as outTime      
from #tempStatus where sStatus = 2      
)b       
group by empId,outTime) t     
on s.EmpId = t.EmpId and Convert(Varchar,s.OutTime,112) =  Convert(Varchar,t.outTime,112)      

select * from #tempA order by EmpId      

drop table #tempA      
DROP TABLE #tempStatus
```

Here is the demo- [**Spltting Column**](https://rextester.com/MGOBD89330)